# How to install older GDAL v1.11 on Ubuntu 16.04 instead of v2.1.3

Tags: gdal, ubuntugis, ogrinfo

I have another question going on this forum regarding GDAL 2.1 ogrinfo not working at [Trying to get GDAL 2.x to work, but ogrinfo reports ERROR 3: and ERROR 4: and "Failed to open table res_t48.PAT"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253103/trying-to-get-gdal-2-x-to-work-but-ogrinfo-reports-error-3-and-error-4-and-f), but in parallel, as a fix to an apparently "broken" ogrinfo 2.1 reading coverages, I'd like to see if I can just go back to gdal v1.11 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Can anyone tell me how to install an older version of gdal on Ubuntu 16.04 when "apt-get install gdal-bin" installs v2.1.3?  What repositories do I have to point to, or what packages do I install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see what versions are available on the repository using `apt-cache policy gdal-bin` and then install a specific version using `sudo apt-get install gdal-bin=1.11`

[UbuntuGIS](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) has several versions available and can be added as a repository using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa`

Comment: Thank you! `apt-cache policy gdal-bin` returns `1.11.3+dfsg-3build2` and `apt-get install gdal-bin=1.11.3+dfsg-3build2` installs it.